# How do I create a model based on another model?

Tags: c#, model

Cum creez un model de  bazat pe un alt model?
Pentru că aș dori să selectez doar proprietățile necesare.

Example:

```
public class Test {
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2{ get; set; }
    public decimal prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to look like:

```
public class TestViewModel {
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to do this, because I want to make views, and the model to contain only the necessary data

Comment: you can use AutoMapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you should create the Views from scratch, no inheritance whatsoever.

The only relation between the Model and the View should be the View's c-tor, which will get a parameter of type Model.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class Test: TestViewModel
{
      public string prop2{ get; set; }
   
}
```